# Android - Custom Animation on fragment transaction not running

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

**I'm using Google API 8 (Android 2.2) with support package v4.**

It doesn't give any error or animation.

Transaction:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();       
transaction.replace(R.id.content, myFragment);
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
transaction.commit();
```

Animations:

**slide_in_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

**slide_out_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: Fragments weren't introduced until Honeycomb (API 11, Android 3.0). That could be the problem, but I would have thought Eclipse would tell you.

Comment: That's why I'm using the support package.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

The manager was stacking my transaction before I set the animation, so it stacks the transaction without animations (sad but true), and that occurs even if I commit the transaction after the `setCustomAnimations()`.

The solution is to set the animations first:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();       
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
transaction.replace(R.id.content, myFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: so you have to split the statement avoiding the self returned object trick

Comment: `transaction.something().somethingelse().replace().commit()`, many of android methods return `this` so you can avoid retyping the variable, but somehow here exposes a side effect and `setCustomAnimations()` should be called separately

Comment: Just to note, "self returned object trick" is called "method chaining"

Comment: Method chaining the above call definitely works. Just tested it in my own project.

Comment: For additional, to animate fragment when pop from back stack, use `transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);` instead.

Comment: Deserves a +1. That's a life saver for me.
It's sad that 5 years later and the issue is not solved... it is called a transaction for a reason !!! Why would order of call cause a problem?

Answer (score 26):

As suggested above, separate statements will definitely work. But the **trick here** is to `setCustomAnimation` before setting transaction type viz.`add`, `replace`, etc. else it doesn't. So, applying the same logic, `method chaining` also works. eg.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.a_slide_up,
                             R.anim.a_slide_down,
                             R.anim.a_slide_up,
                             R.anim.a_slide_down)
        .add(R.id.root_layout, 
             MyFrag.newInstance())
        .addToBackStack("MyFrag")
        .commit();
```

Putting it here, so that someone who prefers `method chaining` finds it helpful. Cheers!

Comment: I'm mildly offended by the way you use the 'dot' operator for method chaining.

Comment: Agreed @Shaishav, wrote this answer two years ago, updating it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Leaving this here as it's the most popular question. I had the same problem with fragment transaction not animating. The culprit was having the attribute `android:animateLayoutChanges` set to `true` in the containing layout.

I hope it helps someone save some time looking for a solution as it can be hard to notice when having nested layouts in different files.

Comment: Animation working now but new problem- it is changed animation behavior. before it is sliding horizontally (as expected). now expanding from corner

Answer (score 0):

Another reason can be unnecessarily placing `fragmentTransaction.show()` before commit. This makes pop transitions not show on some android API versions.

Answer (score 0):

for me the problem was using `Fragment.getChildFragmentManager()` I switched to `Fragment.getParentFragmentManager()` and animations suddenly started working.