# Slide left/right animation between fragments

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I post a question here because I can't find out a solution to my problem. I read a lot of things about android animation.

I actually develop an android 4.0 app and I need to animate transition between fragments (not layout).

[Similary post, worked with layout but no more precision about fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments)

Here my uncomplete code :

**Activity code**

```
private void showFragment(final Fragment fragment)
{
    if (null == fragment)
        return;

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container_layout, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();

}
```

**R.anim.slide_in_left**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

And finally **R.anim.slide_out_right**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />

</set>
```

When I run this code, I got an exception : 
**12-27 15:26:55.566: E/AndroidRuntime(27699): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animator name: translate**

Do you have any idea to fix this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Custom Animation on fragment transaction not running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041325/android-custom-animation-on-fragment-transaction-not-running)

Comment: Have you check this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932462/animate-the-transition-between-fragments

Comment: aegean : it's look like, but not a duplicate
@PiyushGupta : yes I already read, I tried too and I got another error : Method setXFraction() with type float not found on target class class android.widget.LinearLayout

Comment: For that you have to use FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout

Comment: So I need to have a FrameLayout subclass per view I need to animate ?

Comment: Thank you @PiyushGupta, I thought there was a less boring way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

Like Piyush Gupta said, I must have a custom subclass of `FrameLayout` per `Fragment` I need to animate, first.

Secondly, I must not use `R.anim` but `R.animator` like another similar post (link in question).

Thank you all !