# Making a flipping Android animation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation

I am very weak with animations in Android. I need to make my Fragments "flip" just 100% equal to the `ViewPager` animation.

Here is my `slide_in_left.xml` code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
  <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromXDelta="-100%"
   android:toXDelta="0"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
   android:duration="5000"/>
</set>
```

Here is my `**slide_out_right.xml**` code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
  <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromXDelta="0"
   android:toXDelta="-100%"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
   android:duration="5000"/>
</set>
```

But this is not equal to `ViewPager` sliding animation. Instead, the existing `Fragment` exists from left and the new `Fragment` enters from left.

Apart from that, I need this animation to exit the existing fragment from left and new one to enter from right. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Refer this link.Hope it will help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802369/slide-left-right-animation-between-fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do any changes in slide_out_right.xml. But in slide_in_left.xml, just replace

```
android:fromXDelta="-100%"
```

with

```
android:fromXDelta="100%"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But there is a small difference. ViewPager existing Fragment exists from left, new one enter from right. Here it is other way around

Answer (score 0):

First, in your slide_out_right.xml, change

```
android:toXDelta="-100%p"
```

to

```
android:toXDelta="100%p"
```

And I think you should as well set animation for slide to right, a slide_in_right.xml and slide_out_left.xml

see [FragmentTransaction#setCurrentAnimations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)