# Trouble with animating fragment transaction animation

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I am having some trouble trying to set custom animation to my fragment transaction. I know there are several treads on this and I have tried all their soluction and I still cant get this to work. Here are the animation xml files:

slide.down.xml(for exit)

```
<set xmlns:android="”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="700"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

slide_up.xml(for entering)

```
<set xmlns:android="”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="700"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="-100%"/>
```

and my fragment transaction code:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up , R.anim.slide_down,R.anim.slide_up , R.anim.slide_down)
                            .replace(R.id.container, list)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

All the solutions form other similar threads I have tried:

- Made sure `setCustomAnimations` is before `replace`
- Have set `android:hardwareAccelerated` to true in the Manifest.
- Made sure animations are not disabled in the developer options on my test device

I seem to be messing something very obvious and important but I cant figure out what that is.

My question: Why doesn't my costume animation work and how do I get it to work ?

Comment: doesn't you have to use Animators,  and not Animations?

Comment: I dont understand you, are you saying I should not use setCustomAnimations ? Why not ?

Comment: no,  i am saying you should use objectAnimator in your xml file

Comment: Several people have implemented the way I have done it and it seems to work fine for them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041325/android-custom-animation-on-fragment-transaction-not-running?rq=1  Can you link me to some examples where objectAnimator is used?

Comment: this is because they are using support library,  and it uses Animations,  4+ code uses Animators,  not Animations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, there are two types of animations in Android. *View* Animation ([Animation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html)) and *Property* Animation ([Animator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html)). Your animations are the former, while `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations` expects the latter. You have 2 options to fix this:

1. Use the support library.

   - Subclass `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`
   - Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` to create the `FragmentTransaction`
2. Use Animators

   - Create a custom parent `ViewGroup` (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4936159/377260))
   - Create the `objectAnimator` (XML)

The first option is definitely the easier one, especially since you're going for a on/off screen translation, and it expects the types of animations that you've already defined.

To learn more about the difference between the two animations, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#property-vs-view).

Comment: ad 2) you only need to have an Animator:  either defined in xml or returned by Fragment.onCreateAnimator()

Comment: @pskink If you want to translate a view on/off screen, like he's doing above, you must create a custom parent with `Animator`.

Comment: ok i overlooked "-100%", so in this case static xml file is not enough,  but still you can override onCreateAnimatior without custom root ViewGrnoup

Comment: Hey @PaulBurke, and doing the fragment transactions in my FragmentActivity so I am importing android.support . v4 . app . FragmentActivity. I have replaced getFragmentManager() with getSupportFragmentManager(), but I am still not seeing the transaction animation. :(