# I can't get the same animation between activity and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, android-activity, fragment

For animation between fragment I'm using the folder anim with the translate tag like this, I got 4 files :
 slide in from left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="230"/>
</set>
```

slide out to left

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="230" />
</set>
```

slide in from right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="230"/>
</set>
```

slide out to right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="230" />
</set>
```

This works well between activity, the previous activity translate to the left and the new one appears from the right.

But I can't get the same animation when I call a fragment from an activity.
I'm not using the support fragment so I need to use animation with object animator like this :

```
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="400"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="2000"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

I got 4 files again for the animation and I'm using it like this :

```
  transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_from_left, R.animator.slide_out_to_left, R.animator.slide_in_from_right, R.animator.slide_out_to_right);
```

But with this animation the fragment come from the right and come above the activity I would like that the activity translate to the left 
I try to animate the activity just before call the fragment but this is not working :

```
findViewById(R.id.main_view).startAnimation( AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MatchActivity.this, R.anim.slide_out_to_left));
```

How can I translate the activity when I'm calling the new fragment I want to have the same transition animation between all my view

Comment: There is a certain place you should perform `setCustomAnimations()`. If you  set that line after `add()` or `replace()`, those animations won't be respected.

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/11108301/1083957

Comment: My fragment animations works fine I just want to know how can I get the same animation with translate when I use object animators.
Because actually when I call the fragment animation the fragment come above the activity and I want that the previous activity slide on the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your fragment like this
getSupportFragmentManagr().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right).replace(R.id.frame, new Settings_Fragment(), "YOUR_TARGET_FRAGMENT_TAG").addToBackStack("4").commit();